# How GNU make manages file version control?

Tags: makefile, build, gnu-make, build-automation

I'm learning `GNU make` . Suppose I have a `hello_world.c` file and a `Makefile`:
**hello_world.c:**

```
#include <stdio.h>                        

int main() {                              
        printf("Hello World!\n");  
        return 0;                         
}
```

**Makefile:**

```
hello: hello_world.c
        gcc hello_world.c -o hello_world
```

Now, I think `hello` is my target and `hello_world.c` is its dependency. If make **somehow detects** that `hello_world.c` is newer than its object-file, it executes the corresponding command.

**1-** How does `make` manage file version control and how does it detect something is newer than something else and needs updating?
**2-** If I change `hello_world.o` using an editor and corrupt the file, it obviously does not execute but `make hello` reports that **nothing needs to be done!** 
I mean, `make` only checked that the dependency is older than the target and exited doing nothing. I think it should have detected that this target is not the one corresponding to its latest invocation. Somehow, it should have compared the "*combination of dependency AND target*" history instead of just comparing dependency's history w.r.t. target.
**3-** Is this the limitation of `make`? How can I circumvent this issue? Because there maybe some external apps messing with the target of my make operation.

Comment: Try making your Makefile a single line: `hello: hello_world.o`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **1**- How does `make` manage file version control and how does it detect something is newer than something else and needs updating?

You already know the answer to this question. You said it in your next paragraph: "I mean, `make` only checked that the dependency is older than the target and exited doing nothing." That's right. `make` updates dependent targets when the dependencies of targets are newer.

> **2**- If I change `hello_world.o` using an editor and corrupt the file, it obviously does not execute but `make hello` reports that **nothing needs to be done!** I mean, `make` only checked that the dependency is older than the target and exited doing nothing. I think it should have detected that this target is not the one corresponding to its latest invocation. Somehow, it should have compared the "*combination of dependency AND target*" history instead of just comparing dependency's history w.r.t. target.

You are asking `make` to do a lot more than what it was intended to do.

> **3**- Is this the limitation of `make`? How can I circumvent this issue? Because there maybe some external apps messing with the target of my make operation.

From your point of view, it does seem like it is a limitation of `make`. However, I want to point out that you are sabotaging the workings of `make` by updating a target manually.

How can you circumvent it?

1. Don't manually modify targets that are built by `make`.
2. Manually update the time stamp of one of the dependencies and then run `make`. You can use the command `touch` for that.
3. Provide a dummy target named `clean` that will remove all the dependent targets. Then, run `make clean` followed by `make`.
4. Provide a dummy target named `rebuild`. Forcefully build whatever you need to build in that target. Then, run `make rebuild`.

Comment: So the most conservative solution is `make rebuild` which does not have any dependency and  simply executes all other rules's commands no matter what? And is this the same thing we click rebuild project in IDEs?

Comment: @Zeta.Investigator. Yes. However, you can reduce the code duplication in the Makefile by executing `make clean` and `make` as the only commands under that target.

Comment: @Zeta.Investigator Your makefile won't generate a `.o` file, so you cannot manually edit that non-existent file, because you are asking the compiler to directly create the executable. The problem you describe does just not happen. If you change your dependences by `hello: hello_world.o`, and `hello_world.o: hello_world.cpp`, and then you edit `hello_world.o`, GNU Make will execute the `hello: hello_world.o`'s recipe (do the linking again).

Answer (score 1):

The `make` program simply compare the modification time-stamps of the target (`hello`) and the dependency (`hello_world.c`) files.

If the time-stamp of a dependency file is newer than the targets, then it execute the commands.

Comment: OK, Any ideas about 2 and 3?

Answer (score 1):

> How does make manage file version control and how does it detect something is newer than something else and needs updating?

Very simple: `make` does not care about file versions.

Detecting if something is newer than something else is simply done by comparing time stamps from file system.

> If I change hello_world.o using an editor and corrupt the file, it obviously does not execute but make hello reports that nothing needs to be done!  I mean, make only checked that the dependency is older than the target and exited doing nothing. I think it should have detected that this target is not the one corresponding to its latest invocation. Somehow, it should have compared the "combination of dependency AND target" history instead of just comparing dependency's history w.r.t. target.

You did not tell `make` anything about your .o file. Why should `make` check the timestamp of that file?
Checking the dependency is exactly what `make` is expected to do.
How should this tool possibly know that a file calles `hello_world.o` is involved in the process if you don't tell it? There is no magic happening but only the rules of your Makefile are followed.

> Is this the limitation of make? How can I circumvent this issue? Because there maybe some external apps messing with the target of my make operation.

You can specify hierarchical dependencies:

```
all: hello

hello: hello_world.o
    <gcc linker command...>

hello_world.o: hello_world.c
    gcc hello_world.c -o hello_world
```

Comment: So in your proposed Makefile, If I corrupt hello_world.o, make first looks at all, then hello, then checks if hello_world.o is newer than hello? But hello itself is not a file...

Comment: Corrupting files that are not source files is a bad idea. Of course they are not recreated from the source resulting in linker errors etc. You should define your output file as target. Otherwise which file should be compared as reference to rebuild?

Comment: If make somehow saved a copy of hashes of files, or did some vc like git does, it could have done my request, right?

Comment: You are mixing tools. Make is neither a database, nor a VC system. It is a scanner for dependencies that are completely specified in your Makefile. It is up to you to specify correct dependencies and rules.

Comment: "it could have done my request, right?" Yes, a completely different tool could handle your request.